# How to make a vertical line chart?

Tags: r

Here is small example of data:

```
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
height measurement temperature
h1  m1  24.5
h2  m1  24.0
h3  m1  25.0
h4  m1  16.0
h1  m2  22.0
h2  m2  25.0
h3  m2  23.5
h4  m2  17.0
h1  m3  23.2
h2  m3  24.2
h3  m3  23.0
h4  m3  16.9
 ')

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=temperature, y=height, colour=measurement)) +
  geom_point(shape=19, size=2.5) +
  xlim(15, 30)
```

I want to make a vertical line graph. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeCrC.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were almost there:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=temperature, y=height, colour=measurement, group=measurement)) +
  geom_point(shape=19, size=2.5) +
  geom_path() +
  xlim(15, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help. I would suggest playing around with colors to get the exact feel.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(temperature, factor(height), color=measurement)) + geom_path(aes(temperature, factor(height), group=measurement))
```